# Material UI issue with ISO 8601 date format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

Server returns date as `birthDate: "2023-11-10T05:00:00.000Z"` ISO 8601 format. When trying to display this in MUI `DatePicker` using React-Hook_Form to replace the `defaultValue`, I am getting a type error: `TypeError: value.isBefore is not a function` which indicates that MUI's `DatePicker` is not able to understand this value. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props {
  control: Control;
  name: string;
  label: string;
}

const DateInput: React.FC<Props> = ({ control, name, label }) => {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={dayjs(new Date())}
        render={({ field: { ref, ...rest } }) => (
          <DatePicker label={label} format="MM-DD-YYYY" {...rest} />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, I guess you are passing the value to the Date picker by spreading `...rest`.

The problem should not be related to the format of the date but it should be because you are not passing that string into `dayjs`.

By doing some experiments with the component I could guess you are passing directly the **date received from the back-end as a normal string**.

This won't work because the `DatePicker` uses the object generated by `dayjs` to work with dates. So every time you pass/update a value you have to transform it using `dayjs`.

So your DatePicker should look something along the way of this:

```
// Where props.dateFromBackend is "2023-11-10T05:00:00.000Z"
<DatePicker label="Controlled picker" value={dayjs(props.dateFromBackend)} />
```

Link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-archimedes-h4s8rl

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it solved my issue!